# HPlip cannot find printer/scanner (HP Envy 5010)

Tags: cups, printer, sane, hplip, hp-printer

Santa brought me a new printer - an HP Envy 5010 but I can't get it working.

The paper documentation supplied with the printer was useless (omitted to mention that you need to / how to open the case and install ink cartridges) and the only setup information was to "download the app for iphone or android". Running this app on my tablet, it discovered the device without any problem.

hp-setup cannot find the printer - I've tried the 3 auto-discovery methods in hplip (SLP, bonjour/mdns, avahi) even if I tell it the printer's IP address (as reported in lcd screen on the printer). I have tried each of 1-4 as options for "jetdirect port". There is no firewall between my Linux host and the printer.

From the command line, I can connect to ports 631 and 9100 using telnet, and to the http and https admin consoles. But I can't connect to 161 and 162 which are described in the troubleshooting at https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/KnowledgeBase/Troubleshooting/TroubleshootNetwork

Cups has discovered the printer (twice!):

```
 Discovered Network Printers: 
   HP ENVY 5000 series [0531AC] (HP HP ENVY 5000 series)
   ENVY 5000 All-in-One Printer series (HP ENVY 5000 series)
```

Meanwhile, HP says they don't provide *any* drivers for it at https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/model/14095645

(but that is auto-detecting my Linux OS, shame HPLIP wasn't so good) Unfortunately none of the drivers listed for other OS seem to have a seperate PPD file and my CUPS installation doesn't have one for an Envy 5010. The  one for a HP Envy 5530 seems to be working with the test page).

Has anyone successfully configured an HP Envy 5010 to scan? How?

Should I expect to have to reconfigure CUPS if the IP address changes?

Comment: I managed to get the scanning working by inserting the models.dat from the current release of hplip into /usr/share/hplip/data/models/ This still does not list the 5010, but the 5000 driver worked with simple-scan / subsequently I launched xsane - it found the device without having to be told (remembered from previous invocation?). So I just need to worry about what happens when the address changes.

Comment: Please make that an Answer, as Comments are transient.